# BLDC Outrunner Motor Windings

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Is there a specific way Outrunners are normally wound? (Wye or Delta)

What are the pros/cons to winding the motor a certain way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Wye connected BLDC motor will have a \$K_t\$ that is \$\sqrt3\$ larger than a delta connected motor (assuming they are wound exactly the same.  This means that delta connected motors will run faster for a given voltage and produce less torque for a given current.

The only issue you may run into with delta connected windings is that each phase needs to be identical in resistance or you can get circulating currents that don't produce useful power (making the motor less efficient).

Comment: Indeed. So in conclusion: outrunner or not is not related to Y or delta-connections.

Answer (score 0):

Motor is wound always the same, you then connect windings in wye or delta. you can cobine two voltage levels like 230/400V (delta/wye) in wye you have more losses in copper, also it is more expensive due to more copper used. Idealy you would connect in delta connection if it is possible.